# How to scan devices on network

Tags: android, cordova

I am looking for a way to scan for all devices on a same network (connected to a same AP.)

For example, I have a RaspberryPi device, and I want to connect to it from Cordova app automatically - without user interaction. Therefore I thought I'd do a scan of all devices and just return the IP of Raspberry device.

I looked in Cordova plugins and only found [Network Information](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/) which is not capable of doing it.

I also tried using [Cordova Service Discovery plugin](https://github.com/hsccorp/cordova-plugin-discovery) which does a search for active SSDP / UPnP / DLNA services on a local network. This does work, I am able to retrieve the Raspberry IP by running a SSDP service on it. How ever the problem is that it doesn't work on newest Android versions. (I didn't test on iOS yet)

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Having the same issue!

Comment: @Blackfaded In the end I used bluetooth to send the IP from Raspberry to Cordova app.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with zeroconf in cordova and mdns-js in my electron app.